# Fb api Post share image link display empty image

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I need a help to facebook  share image link using node.js fb api.

```
      var attachment = {
               message: 'test message',

            picture : 'http://localhost:1337/images/image3.jpg',
            link : options.link,
            name: 'Go to image',
            caption: 'taged you in a photo',
            description: 'test 2'

        }; 


      FB.api('me/feed', 'post', attachment, function(res) {
            if (!res || res.error) {
                console.log("facebook error");
                console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
            }else{
                console.log("facebook");
                 Logger("successfully posted", res);
            }

        });
```

the above code,working but, image display in empty.
 I want to image clickable. user click  image redirect my page.

plz anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share image from `localhost:#port`, since **fb** has no access to it. Only images with public access can be used by a facebook post.